# Sequence detector doesn't work as expected

Tags: verilog, simulation, xilinx, system-verilog

I am trying to write Verilog code to do a sequence detector in the state diagram below. Input is a 2-bit signal, and there are 3 states as in the image.

The goal is to detect the sequence (01)-(11). When this sequence is detected, the output (1 bit signal) is 1.

I tried the code below, but somehow it doesn't work as expected. In my first test, if I set up reset as zero all the time, then the output signal some part is correct and some part isn't.

[image]

However, when I set a reset at the rising edge of clock, the output is always zero and two registers state and next_state is always unknown.
Could anyone tell me what is wrong with it and how to fix it?

[image]

[image]

```
module SeqDect(rst,clk,ip,op);

output reg op;
input clk, rst;
  input [1:0] ip;
reg [1:0] state;
reg [1:0] next_state;

  parameter [1:0] s0=2'b00;
  parameter [1:0] s1=2'b01;
  parameter [1:0] s2=2'b10;

always @(posedge clk, posedge rst)
begin
if (rst)
  state=s0;
    else
  state=next_state;
end

always @(state, next_state)
begin
case(state)
s0:
if (ip==2'b01)
  begin
    next_state=s1;
    op=1'b0;
  end
  else
  begin
    next_state=s0;
    op=1'b0;
  end
 
    s1:
  if (ip==2'b11)
  begin
    next_state=s2;
    op=1'b1;
  end
  else if (ip==2'b01)
  begin
    next_state=s1;
    op=1'b0;
  end
  else 
  begin
    next_state=s0;
    op=1'b0;
  end

    s2:
  if (ip==2'b11)
  begin
    next_state=s2;
    op=1'b1;
  end
  else if (ip==2'b01)
  begin
    next_state=s1;
    op=1'b0;
  end
  else
  begin
    next_state=s0;
    op=1'b0;
  end
 
    default:
  begin
          next_state=s0;
          op=1'b0;
  end
    endcase
end
endmodule
```

Comment: You should be using non-blocking assignments to update `state`. Beyond that, if you have a working simulation you can examine internal signals to see where things go wrong. That's much better than trying to debug code by inspection.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I fixed it but the result is same. It doesn't change anything. The problem is still that state and next_state variable are always unknown as in the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `always` block is a sequential circuit, so you should use non-blocking assignments.

Your second `always` block is a combinational circuit, and you must declare all the **input signals** in the sensitivity list.  Or you can use `always @(*)`

(Line 16,18,21 changed)

```
    module SeqDect(rst,clk,ip,op);
    
   /*io and internal wires*/
    
    always @(posedge clk, posedge rst)
    begin
    if (rst)
      state<=s0;
        else
      state<=next_state;
    end
    
    always @(state, ip)
    begin
    case(state)
    /*cases*/
        endcase
    end
    endmodule
```

testbench module:

```
module tb();

reg rst;
reg clk;
reg [1:0] ip;
wire op;

SeqDect uut(rst,clk,ip,op);

always #20 clk =~clk;

initial begin
clk=0;
rst=1;
#100
rst=0;
#100
ip = 2'b00;
#100
ip = 2'b01;
#100
ip = 2'b11;
#100
$stop;
end
endmodule
```

Modelsim simulation results:

[image]